# developing maven plugin, how to exclude bitkeeper files

Tags: maven-2

I'm writing a maven 2 plugin and I'd like to exclude all the java files related to the source repository I'm using, which is BitKeeper.  These files live in directories called SCCS.  So far, I've been unsuccessful.

When I add the maven-compile-plugin with excludes data, it works (the BitKeeper files are excluded) if I execute mvn compiler:compile.  But this is not binding to the compile phase.  So that when I run mvn compile, it blows up trying to compile a source control specific java file.  Any help or pointers appreciated.

Another thing to note: Everything works perfectly if I change the packaging from "maven-plugin" to "jar", which of course, I can't do permanently since this is a maven plugin I am trying to write.

I'm sorry if this is answered elsewhere.  I've looked around for several hours here and through the maven docs, but everything on this topic seems to be related to writing code which will be packaged in jars, not maven plugins.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycomp.mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>special-persistence-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Special Persistence Plugin</name>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <excludes>
           <exclude>**/SCCS/**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <phase>compile</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>compiler:compile</goal>
         </goals>         
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Thank you to anyone with ideas about this,

-Denali

Comment: Are you sure that the build fails during `compile`? Could you please run `mvn generate-resources` and confirm if it works? I don't think it will. Thanks

Comment: OK - you're right.  It doesn't fail during compile.  Compilation succeeds.  It fails on the plugin-descriptor goal, which comes later in the compile phase.  

How can I indicate to this goal that is should ignore all SCCS directories and any java files in them?

Comment: And yes, mvn generate-resources also fails on the same goal.
    [plugin:descriptor {execution: default-descriptor}]
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to read mojo metadata.
    [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
    [INFO] 
    [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] syntax error @[1,2] in file:/home/dlumma/work/bk/cimguitest-5.0-trunk/stsweb/src/main/java/com/coverity/sts/SCCS/p.STSMojo.java

p.STSMojo.java should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [**`plugin:descriptor`**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-plugin-plugin/descriptor-mojo.html) is triggered during the `generate-resources` phase which precedes `compile` (see the [lifecycle reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) for a packaging of type `maven-plugin`).

Anyway, the problem here is that regardless of the reason of the failure (even if the mojo had been able to parse `p.STSMojo.java` that must contain some unexpected header, the plugin doesn't allow a Mojo to be present twice), the [Maven Plugin Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-plugin-plugin/) **doesn't** support includes/excludes (see [MPLUGIN-15](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPLUGIN-15) and go vote for it) and I'm not sure that you can solve this by configuration.

Maybe  you can generate the plugin descriptor while the code is not under version control, put the descriptor in `/META-INF/maven/plugin.xml` and configure the Maven plugin plugin to skip the descriptor generation. But I didn't test this.

Or maybe you could (clean or dirty) fix the plugin. But I didn't look at the source so I can't say much about this.

Or, and this is certainly not the expected answer but still the most simple, you could maybe use another VCS for your mojo (just for the Mojo, why not in parallel of bitkeeper).

I'd start with a comment on the Jira issue (your use case is perfectly valid and should be supported), you might get better ideas there.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  I ended up moving the source files into a new location, generating the plugin jar, and then moving them back and checking it in.  Yuck.  But it worked.  I've also contacted BitKeeper.  Apparently they are removing the SCCS dirs in the next release, but have no ETA for when that will be.  It's a big problem with the current BitKeeper version, and it's known.  I'll also post a request for include/exclude support in the plugin template on the forums you provide.  Thank you, again.

Comment: @Denali You're welcome. And thank you for the feedback. It's good to know bitkeeper folks are working on this but I don't really understand how this differs from CVS. Maven should be able to ignore SCCS directories.